# How to write better template tags in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I've seen how I can write template tags that set a context variable based on a template like this

```
{% my_template_tag 'blah' as my_context_variable %}
```

But I'd like to be able to do this:

given that both `group` and `user` are set in the context in the view

```
{% is_in_group group user as is_member %}

{% if is_member %}
   #.... do stuff ....
{% endif %}
```

or ideally something like this:

```
{% if is_in_group group user %}
   # ....
{% end if %}
```

Obviously the other way round is to just set `is_member` in the view - but this is just an example and would be good to know how to do something like this anyway!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Evgeny has a good idea with the smart_if template tag. However, if that doesn't work, you will probably find that a custom filter is easier to write for this sort of comparison. Something like:

```
@register.filter
def is_in(obj, val):
    return val is in obj
```

and you would use it like this:

```
{% if user|is_in:group.users %}
```

Comment: genius. use a filter not a tag - didn't think of that!

Comment: `val is in obj` is invalid syntax, should be `val in obj`

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with `{{ perms.model_name.permission_name }}`?  (Comes with [django.core.context_processors.auth](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-auth).)

Django groups are just collections of permissions, and allowing or disallowing access to a particular item should be by individual permission.

Or, if you really want to write your own tag or filter, there's [lots of documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). And if that doesn't work, there are other template languages that you can use that might do what you want better.

*However*, I expect that writing a tag will be unnecessary. Django is pretty good at having already figured out what you really want to do. Sometimes it takes a little digging to find out though.

Comment: sorry - the use of `groups` was a bit confusing - in this case I have groups in my app (not auth groups) and in particular wanted to see if the current user was a member of the current 'group' - if not, then show a "join group" button, if so, show a "leave group" button.

Answer (score 3):

try this using [smart if](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/) tag:

```
{% if group in user.groups %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's filter should do the trick. As a template tag it could be something like this:

```
class IsInGroupNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, group, user, varname):
        self.member =  template.Variable(user)
        self.group = template.Variable(group)
        self.varname = varname


    def render(self, context):
        self.group = self.group.resolve(context)
        self.user = self.user.resolve(context)
        context[self.varname] = self.user in self.group.user_set.all()
        return  ''


def is_in_group(parser, token):
    bits = token.contents.split()
    #some checks
    return IsInGroupNode(bits[1], bits[2],bits[4])

is_in_group = register.tag(is_in_group)
```

In the template you would use your tag signature

```
{% is_in_group group user as is_member %}
```