# Compare attributes of a Django Queryset in a template using the `in` Operator

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the [`in` operator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator) to determine if a template variable on the current page is also a foreign key in another model.

The model is like so:

```
class WishlistItem(models.Model):
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='wishlist_items')
    issue = models.ForeignKey(Issue)
```

On the "Issue" page template, I'm trying to do this:

```
{% if issue in user.wishlist_items %}
{% else %}
    {# A button to add the issue to the user's wishlist #}
{% endif %}
```

What I need to do is to get at the `issue` attribute of the `wishlist_items` QuerySet for the currently logged-in user and compare it to the `issue` object of the current page. I'm at a loss for how to do this. Do I need to write a templatetag to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by writing a [template filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters):

```
@register.filter
def in_list(obj, arg):
    "Is the issue in the list?"
    return obj in (item.issue for item in arg)
```

Then I could do something like this in a template:

```
{% if issue|in_list:user.wishlist_items.all %}
```

I got the idea from [the answer on this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827976/how-to-write-better-template-tags-in-django/1828239#1828239).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there's a relationship between `User` and wishlist issues that you ought to express as a `ManyToManyField` on the `User`. If there is extra metadata about the relationship that you need to record in a `WishlistItem`, then use `through=WishlistItem`.

If the `User` model is from the `auth` app, you'll need to extend the `User` model to achieve this (see [this blog post](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/) for some help). For example:

```
class MyUser(User):
    wishlist_issues = models.ManyToManyField(Issue, through=WishlistItem)
    # ...
```

Then, in your template use:

```
{% if issue not in user.wishlist_issues %}
    {# A button to add the issue to the user's wishlist #}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are refering to should go into the view, more than the template.
Of course, you could create some templatetag, however Django's approach to templates is to maintain them as dumb as possible, and move all logic to the view.

On the other hand, moving the logic in the view, and then passing the additional information to the template should be quite straightforward, and I would definitely go for that solution.

Answer (score 0):

`wishlist_items` is not a queryset - it's a manager. `wishlist_items.all` IS a queryset, but obviously it is a queryset of `WishlistItem` objects, not `Issue` objects. What I would do is handle this logic in the view... something like:

```
user_has_issue = issue in (wl.issue for wl in request.user.wishlist_items.all())
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the "best" solution to the problem, but it's doing the trick for me right now, and I can understand it. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, instead of writing a templatetag for it you can pass that as a parameter of the view.

```
def myView(request):
    return render_to_response('template.html', 
            {'query': queryToCheckIfIssueInWishList}, 
            RequestContext(request))
```